# passing the function to onClick argument

Tags: reactjs

Could you explain me why these two snippets work differently?

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.props.openImageSelector()
  }

{...}
<MyButton
 onClick={this.handleClick}
>
{...}
```

that one work as expected: calls the function after clicking on the button.

```
{...}
<MyButton
 onClick={this.props.openImageSelector()}
>
{...}
```

that one, on the other hand, calls the function once when the component is rendered and then clicking doesn't work. Where the difference come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `()` at the end of the function `openImageSelector`, which makes the function to execute and assign the return value (if any) to the onClick.

Thats why the function gets executed when the component is rendered.

Comment: Thank you. That's the easiest to understand answer from all of the above.

Answer (score 2):

the Difference is about calling or passing,

on your first example, you call a function whenever component clicked,

on your second example, you pass a function whenever component clicked,

Answer (score 1):

On your first example, `onClick` contains the reference towards the `handleClick` method.

On your second example, `onClick` directly execute the function `openImageSelector`. What you would need to do instead is : `onClick={() => this.props.openImageSelector()}`.